# Parsing a json file using jQuery

Tags: jquery, json

```
{

 "abc": [ 
        {

            "1":"a",
            "2":"b"

        } 
    ]

}
```

I am using jQuery to parse and generate the HTML

```
$.getJSON('my.json', function(data) {
      var items = [];
      $.each(data.abc, function(key,val) {
        items.push('<li id="' + key + '">' + val + '</li>');
      });

      $('<ul/>', {
        'class': 'display',
        html: items.join('')
      }).appendTo('#abc');
    });
```

But it give me undefined

Comment: your array only has one item.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your solution is pretty simple, basically remove the square brackets.

You're trying to run an each on a hash, but you're wrapping that hash with in an array.

Here, checkout the [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/prrgs/) I did to test it out and give you an example.

Basically you need to have this in your JSON file instead.

```
{
    "abc": {
        "1": "a",
        "2": "b"
    }
}
```